# i can't compile with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am trying to compile code with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, but I get the following errors. Can someone help me or explain to me what is the possible reason?

Thank you!

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:70: undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:62: undefined reference to `_fstat'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-openr.o): In function `_open_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/openr.c:59: undefined reference to `_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:58: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:58: undefined reference to `_write'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:53: undefined reference to `_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:58: undefined reference to `_isatty'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:58: undefined reference to `_lseek'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:58: undefined reference to `_read'
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are compiling for a bare-metal target, `newlib` does not by default provide implementations for the functions that make only sense on a system with a console and an hard drive for example, basically system calls such as `read`/`write`/`open`/`close`/...

If you don' t need to those functions, using the `--specs=nosys.specs` option will make your application link with default, basically empty implementations that will return an error code when called:

```
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -o hello hello.c
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:64: undefined reference to `_exit'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:51: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:49: undefined reference to `_write'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:47: undefined reference to `_close'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:49: undefined reference to `_lseek'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:49: undefined reference to `_read'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:55: undefined reference to `_fstat'
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm10--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--arm-none-eabi/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:52: undefined reference to `_isatty'
$
```

Using the `--specs=nosys.specs` option:

```
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -o hello hello.c 
$
```

An alternative, if you want to have your custom implementation of those missing system calls, is to create your own, minimal `syscalls.c` from the `newlib` `libgloss/arm/syscalls.c` source file: you can implement some system calls, and stubbing the others you don't need.
`newlib` source code can be browsed from [here](https://cygwin.com/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=tree), and see section `12 System Calls` and `12.1 Definitions for OS interface` of the `newlib` [documentation](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#SEC_Contents) for more details.